# How to search mongodb collection entry attributes

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a collection in my mongo database by the name "user collection". The collection holds entries with one attribute by the name "DBinstaID".

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5595f6be3eaf90ae2d759cc6"), "DBinstaID" : "280430135" }
```

I am trying to determine whether a new entry has the same DBinstaID value, and if so increase the count of "idCount". The following code is used in my index.js routing file for node.js/express.

```
var collection = db.get('usercollection');

var checkDuplicate = collection.find({$where: function(){this.DBinstaID === instaID}});

  console.log("DUPLICATE STATUS: " + checkDuplicate);

  if(!(checkDuplicate)){
    idCount++;
  }
```

However, the checkDuplicate variable is simply set to [object Object] instead of the boolean true or false. How can I search the collection and return a boolean?

Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `collection.find()` method is asynchronous, this means you can't get the results right away, and you need to handle anything dependant on these results directly in the callback.

I strongly advise you to have a good read of [mongoosejs's docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html) (at least the code examples), and to take a look at basics of asynchronous programming in node.js (a google search away).

You can use [`collection.findOne()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOne) to get only one result :

```
var collection = db.get('usercollection');

collection.findOne({DBinstaID: instaID}, function(err, user) {
    // don't forget to check for errors here, masked for clarity
    console.log("DUPLICATE STATUS: ", user);
    if(user) {
      idCount++;
    }

    // rest of the code
});
```

Comment: Also it worth mentioning that  `$where` should be use only when the query can’t be expressed using another operator

Comment: Yep, forgot to say that in the answer, but I had it in mind, thanks.

Comment: Thank you! I was using this method previously but was using "DBinstaID" instead of saying the attribute name without quotes. Also, this will still print [object Object]. Use console.log("DUPLICATE STATUS: %j, user); to print the entry correctly

Comment: Yep, my bad I didn't see that and edited the code for a cleaner solution than yours (for debugging of course). Just replace the add sign by a comma, so this doesn't concatenate the string and the object, resulting in the "[object Object]" string.

Comment: Hey @saveman71 I have a separate question for you if you have time. When I console.log() the value of idCount inside the scope of collection.findOne the value is 1. When I log again outside the scope, the value returns to 0. Why is that? This is all being run inside a http post request btw

Comment: @prcbass This is exactly a consequence of my first sentence in my answer. The out of scope console.log is executed before the callback of the findOne method is called, so idCount isn't incremented yet. (as you surely noted, the "0" should appear before the "1" when executing the request while the lines of code are reversed, and this is all because the asynchronous nature of callbacks)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer again. I understand what you meant by that now lol. After some googling I'm come to realize I have to do all of this inside the callback function. +1 to you good sir

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the async module https://github.com/caolan/async which provides many useful functions to manage async workflows (the most useful one being async.waterfall)